# php and html link error

Tags: php, html

I have got this link echoed in php:

```
echo "<a href='$appUrl' class='link-wrapper'></a>";
```

$appUrl gives me this:

```
http://example.com/cams2/cam3
```

I am at url before clicking the link:

```
http://example.com/cams1
```

The links html is this:

```
<a href="cams2/cam3/" class="link-wrapper"></a>
```

When I click the url..I get this

```
http://example.com/cams1/cams2/cam3
```

Why are the 2 suburls..are added to the url..why not a new link is generated. like this:
`http://example.com/cams2/cam3` ?

Is it the way browsers behave? can it be htaccess fault..? I dont think that it is..cause when I hover over the link, I see this :http://example.com/cams1/cams2/cam3.. even though what is represented is:

```
http://example.com/cams2/cam3
```

Any idea to why this happens?

**update**

solved.. I did this:
 http://www.example.com/cams2/cam3
That solved the problem..I suspect it was some htaccess problem..no idea why it works

Comment: If you've got a valid reason for using relative URLs, then that's cool. But it's often simpler to use full URLs everywhere to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relative path. It will redirect from present url. You need to write `/url/url2/`. It is called absolute path. It will redirect from root `http://example.com`.

Comment: I think i will accept your answer..cause it provided the most explanation..even though it didnt solve the problem..

Answer (score 4):

Your link is relative and therefore it can't aim to address you want. I think you need to put a slash before your address

```
<a href="/cams2/cam3/" class="link-wrapper"></a>
```

So after all, you just prepend a slash before your `$appUrl`

```
echo "<a href='/$appUrl' class='link-wrapper'></a>";
```

Comment: That didnt solve the problem..What I did ..I used this http://www.example... etc.. hmmm..still dont know what caused it

Comment: What example? The link is broken

Comment: I'm pretty sure you did not do what Martin. (and we all) described.

Comment: I did... that was the first thing that I thought about.. I think the htaccess..was responsible for that

Answer (score 2):

Your link is relative. Add a slash to the front.

Answer (score 2):

That's because html links are relative.

To make them absolute add a slash / to the beginning of your URL.